# Asp.net Web Site Administration Tool with SqlCeMembership

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication, membership-provider

I am developing an application in MVC 3.

I installed [this provider](http://sqlcemembership.codeplex.com/) via Nuget .

Basically, it allows to use any part of memberships, rules and profiles with a .sdf (compact) database.

I need the "Web Site Administration Tool" use this provider. But I can not use it.

Already checked the web.config and everything is ok.

When I open the "Web Site Administration Tool" on the Security I click test (any provider) and the error happens.

The following images.

[image: Providers]

Error when clicking test

[image: Error]

"Could not establish a connection to the database. 
If you have not yet created the SQL Server database, exit the Web Site Administration tool, use the aspnet_regsql command-line utility to create and configure the database, and then return to this tool to set the provider."

**Here part of my web.config**

```
<authentication mode="Forms" />

<membership>
      <providers>
        <add 
          connectionStringName="SqlCeServices" 
          applicationName="/"
          enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
          enablePasswordReset="true" 
          requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
          requiresUniqueEmail="true" 
          passwordFormat="Hashed" 
          writeExceptionsToEventLog="false"
          name="SqlCeMembershipProvider" 
          type="ErikEJ.SqlCeMembershipProvider, ErikEJ.SqlCeMembership" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add 
          name="SqlCeProfileProvider" 
          type="ErikEJ.SqlCeProfileProvider" 
          connectionStringName="SqlCeServices" 
          applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager>
      <providers>
        <add 
          connectionStringName="SqlCeServices" 
          applicationName="/"
          writeExceptionsToEventLog="false" 
          name="SqlCeRoleProvider" 
          type="ErikEJ.SqlCeRoleProvider, ErikEJ.SqlCeMembership" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SqlCeServices" connectionString="data source=|DataDirectory|\SqlCeAspnetdb.sdf" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did alittle research and found this forum post:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/sqlce/thread/8024acc3-8418-4891-875b-8626ce9ba376.

It seems that ASPNETDB.MDF doesnt support SQL Server Compact due to the reasons specified. Can you not use SQL Server Express?